# GeoServer map preview different than OpenLayers output?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, gdaladdo

I have a GeoTIFF with internal overviews, generated using gdaladdo and the -r mode. I published this GeoTIFF in GeoServer 2.6 and I can see the image fine in map preview.

However, when I load the image in our OpenLayers 2 application, the image quality is worse. It appears as though GeoServer Map Preview is using the GeoTIFF overviews that I created using Gdal and that OpenLayers 2 is generating a new overview, using another resampling algorithm.

The layer is loaded in our app by using straight `OpenLayers.Layer.WMS`
Is this even possible? Or am I imagining things?

Answer (score 2):

It was because a difference in the app projection (EPSG:900913) and the layer registered in GeoServer (EPSG:4326). Because of that, the tiles were reprojected using the default method (nearest) and making the image look bad. I publish a new layer in GeoServer, using the correct Web Mercator projection, with overviews created using `mode` method and now everything looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

It may well just be that your app is using a different set of zoom levels, which happen not to match so well the existing overviews

Comment: I'm a bit newbie in openlayers. Is ther a way to check the zoomlevels that my app is using? Can I use the scale text (eg. 1:17M) to see if the zoomlevels are the same?